# $\mathbb{E}X^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)\mathbb{P}(X\ge k)$

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove the following but don't know how:

$\mathbb{E}X^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)\mathbb{P}(X\ge k)$

I proved $\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X\ge k)$
 before but I don't know if that helps here.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq k)$... probably you forgot a sum there, right? Perhaps you might want to apply the (corrected) identity to $X^2$?

Comment: Yes I forgot it. But I don't know what you mean with applying it to $X$^2.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb P(X^2\ge k)=\mathbb P(X\ge\sqrt{k})=\mathbb P(X\ge\Big\lceil\sqrt{k}\Big\rceil)$.

Comment: @Cave Johnson 
Thanks but somehow I can't do this task. That's how I did it for a): $\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X=n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X\ge k)$ Now I don't know how to use this result to prove b)

Comment: Nevermind I got it